# Wordpress localhost URL executing twice

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, localhost

Where is the site url saved? bloginfo('template_url')

every time I click a link I get double my site url. localhost/postmyproject/localhost/postmyproject

I set my site_url, home to: `localhost/postmyproject`

In my wp-config.php file I have the following settings:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'localhost/postmyproject' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'localhost/postmyproject' );
```

My home page code is as follows:

```
do_action('ProjectTheme_top_menu_items');

    $menu_name = 'primary-projecttheme-header';

        if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
            $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
            $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
            foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
                $title = $menu_item->title;
                $url = $menu_item->url;
                    if(!empty($title))
                        echo '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need http:// in front of your SITE_URL as in

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: @KyleLinden Would be nice if you could pass me the accepted answer then (the green check sign to the left of my answer). Hf coding.